# Unstacking a dataframe in R that only has one row for each category

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have the following data frame called `pets` in R:

```
> pets
     name animal
1     Amy    dog
2     Bob    cat
3   Carol    dog
4   Danny    cat
5 Eustace  horse
6 Frances  horse
```

I can `unstack` the data frame to set the animal categories as columns headers like so:

```
> unstack(pets, pets$name ~ pets$animal)
    cat   dog   horse
1   Bob   Amy Eustace
2 Danny Carol Frances
```

If, however, the `pets` data frame only has one instance of each animal:

```
> pets
     name animal
1     Amy    dog
2     Bob    cat
```

then running the same code produces this result:

```
> unstack(pets, pets$name ~ pets$animal)
    res
cat Bob
dog Amy
```

I need something that puts those animal categories as the column headers, regardless of how many rows fall into each category.  Does anyone have any ideas, please?

Comment: Your current code also fails to produce a nice data.frame if you have varying numbers in each category, and will coerce to a list instead. Worth noting.

Comment: Thank you, yes - that's a good point.  With the setup I have, however, I thankfully can be certain that there will always be the same number of rows present for each category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.frame` and `split` will do it:

```
pets <- data.frame(
 name=c("Amy", "Bob", "Carol", "Danny", "Eustace", "Frances"),
 animal=c("dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "horse", "horse")
)

data.frame(split(pets$name,pets$animal,drop=TRUE))

#    cat   dog   horse
#1   Bob   Amy Eustace
#2 Danny Carol Frances

pets2 <- pets[1:2,]

data.frame(split(pets2$name,pets2$animal,drop=TRUE))

#  cat dog
#1 Bob Amy
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  Clearly, I had blinkered myself with the unstack route :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply transpose the result:

```
> t(unstack(pets))
    cat   dog  
res "Bob" "Amy"
```

If you want a solution that will work for both:

```
unstack <- function(..., drop=FALSE) {
  u <- utils::unstack(...)
  if (!drop && ncol(u) == 1) {
    u <- t(u)
    rownames(u) <- 1
    return(u)
  } else {
    return(u)
  }
}
```

This will overwrite the `unstack` function. `drop=TRUE` preserves the default behaviour, while `drop=FALSE` gives you your desired output.

Comment: Thank you, that works with the second example, but unfortunately doesn't work with the first, longer data frame.  I'm ideally looking for a solution that fits both cases.

Comment: Great idea overwriting unstack. I think the condition `ncol(u) == 1`, however, won't ever be met - for all possible inputs, there are always 2 columns.  Somehow, I need to check whether each category has more than 1 row.  This could perhaps be achieved in this specific case with `row(u[2]) == nrow(unique(u[2]))`, but I still get an empty result for the short `pets` data frame

Comment: Actually, I see why `ncol(u) == 1` should work, as it's applied to the result of `unstack(pets)`, however I get an empty result when running `unstack(pets, drop=FALSE)`

Comment: Whoops, missed a return statement -- should work now.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks for the input.  I'm going to run with the `split` suggestion, but I'm really grateful for the time you took.  Good to learn that I can overwrite functions!

Comment: No worries. Just a note on overwriting functions: make sure you identify the package the original function comes from (listed at the top of the help page) so that you can call the original function from your wrapper (i.e. `utils::unstack`). Its easy to forget and accidentally call your wrapper function recursively!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
> p2 <- pets[!duplicated(pets$animal), ]
> data.frame(matrix(p2$name, nrow = 1, ncol = nrow(p2), 
                    dimnames = list(NULL, p2$animal)))
#   dog cat   horse
# 1 Amy Bob Eustace
```